# Is there a simple way to generate default forms (New, Edit, Display) for new custom Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created a number of custom content types representing different types of tasks a user will complete.

EDIT: The custom content types inherit from the built in Task content type, in case that makes any difference.

Each of them have at least one column that is unique to each Content Type, and the unique columns are Site Columns which have been added to the content types. Below is a simplified example using imaginary Content Types

```
Review Task
  - Title
  - Due date
  - Period Start Date (Unique to this CT)
  - Period End Date (Unique to this CT)

Payment Task
  - Title
  - Due date
  - Amount to pay (Unique to this CT)
  - Account Number (Unique to this CT)
```

They will all be stored in the same List, which has "Allow management of content types" selected, and each of the content types has ben added to the List, and appears on the Ribbon under "New Item".

The default forms for this list are used for every content type, and so of course do not display the correct fields based on which type of item the user creates in the list (Via the new item dropdown)

I am looking for the easiest and best way to automatically generate the forms a user could use for:

- New item
- Edit item
- Display item

If these can't be generated automatically from within SharePoint Online, then what is the easiest way to build these forms without a third party, paid product?

I know how to add a new form to the List within SharePoint designer, and how to then have that form show for the respective content type, but I was hoping there's a way to get SharePoint to generate the initial forms automatically.

Comment: The list that was created to store these custom content types was actually a 'Tasks List' - I just create a new 'Custom List' and added one of the content types and this shows the form with the correct fields for different content types - Is the reason this was not working down to the fact it started as tasks list?